# How to add time-varying title for Python matplotlib.animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I am sorry for my poor English.
I have a matrix `datas` (10000 times 5000). It includes 10000 cases of data and the dimension of each data is 5000.
I want to make an animation to show each data one after another.

Following **Code 1** works well.

**(Code 1)**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ims = []

for i in range(10000):
    im = plt.plot(masks[i,:])    
    ims.append(im)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=10)
plt.show()
ani.save('output.mp4', writer="ffmpeg")
```

I want to add the time-varying title to know which data (data index) is shown at a certain time.

And I wrote the following **Code 2**.

**(Code 2)**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig = plt.figure()
ims = []

for i in range(10000):
    im = plt.plot(masks[i,:])    
    tl = 'Data number:' + str(i+1) # ***added***
    plt.title(tl) # ***added*** 
    ims.append(im)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=10)
plt.show()
ani.save('output.mp4', writer="ffmpeg")
```

However, I got an animation whose title is always 'Data number: 10000'.

How can I write the code to add the time-varying title?
I wrote `plt.title(tl)` before `im = plt.plot(masks[i,:])` but nothing changed. Thank you for your help.

My environments are;

- Python 3.6.9
- matplitlib 3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can imitate the figure title by annotating an axes object:

```
#test data generation
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
masks = np.random.randn(10, 15)

#the animation routine starts here
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ims = []

#iterating over the array
for i in range(masks.shape[0]):
    #obtaining the Line2D object representing the line plot
    im, = ax.plot(masks[i,:], color="blue") 
    #creating a centered annotation text above the graph
    ann = ax.annotate(f"This is frame {i:.0f}.", (0.5, 1.03), xycoords="axes fraction", ha="center")
    #collecting both objects for the animation
    ims.append([im, ann])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=300, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```