# show dynamic title on a animate matplotlib hist

Tags: matplotlib, animation, title

I'm trying to add a title or a note (the year actualy plot) who change at each itteration of this annimated plot. The code follow show my last attempt with a note "plt.text".
The variable "yrs" is a list like this [1950, 1951, 1952...2020] I want these value to be show at each frame itteration.

```
# Fixing bin edges
HIST_BINS = np.linspace(data[3].min(), data[var].max(), round(data[var].max())+1)
# histogram our data with numpy
dt = data[var]
dt2 = data[var] # ref
dt2 = dt2[dt2 > 1]
n, _ = np.histogram(dt2, HIST_BINS)

def prepare_animation(bar_container):

    def animate(frame_number):
        # simulate new data coming in
        dt = data.iloc[data.index.year.isin([frame_number]), var]
        dt = dt[dt > 1]
        n, _ = np.histogram(dt, HIST_BINS)
        for count, rect in zip(n, bar_container.patches):
            rect.set_height(count)
        return bar_container.patches

        plt.text(0, 2, str(frame_number),
                 horizontalalignment='left',
                 verticalalignment='center')
     return animate


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(dt2, HIST_BINS, lw=1, weights=np.ones(len(dt2)) / len(dt2)*100,
        color='steelblue', alpha=0.5, label='histo')
_, _, bar_container = ax.hist(dt, HIST_BINS, lw=1, weights=np.ones(len(dt)) / len(dt),
                              color='orange', alpha=0.5, label='window')

ax.set_ylim(top=40)  # set safe limit to ensure that all data is visible.
# ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('mm')
plt.ylabel("freq. %")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, prepare_animation(bar_container), frames=yrs,
                              repeat=False, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you will be able to adapt [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70832956/8881141)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally work... when plot to the screen it doesn't work but the saved .gif work fine....